# QT : QGraphicsTextItem alignment char to top-left corner

Tags: qt, position, alignment, qgraphicstextitem

I want to draw a character aligned to the top-left corner of parent.

```
QGraphicsTextItem * tItem = new QGraphicsTextItem(parent);
tItem->setPlainText("a"); 
tItem->setPos(QPointF(0,0));
```

Picture below presents output of my code (grey rectangle is parent of QGraphicsTextItem)

**Result:**

[image: Result]

I want to get a result like this:

**My dream result:**

[image: My dream result]

I tried to use Qt::AlignLeft and Qt::AlignTop but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `setDocumentMargin(0)` to the `QTextDocument`, if you only put the letter "a" it seems that it is not the solution since there seems to be a vertical offset, but in reality it is not an offset but the capital letters have a higher height.

Example:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsTextItem>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QTextDocument>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsScene scene;
    QGraphicsView view(&scene);
    auto parent = scene.addRect(QRectF(0, 0, 100, 100),  QPen(Qt::red), QBrush(Qt::blue));

    auto * tItem = new QGraphicsTextItem(parent);
    tItem->setPlainText("aAbB");
    tItem->document()->setDocumentMargin(0);
    view.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you for help.
For me solution is using QGraphicsSimpleTextItem and translate by value calculate by QFontMetricsF::tightBoundingRect / QFontMetricsF::boundingRect.